# How To Lookup In An Abnormal Excel Matrix

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

This may get complicated...please bear with me...

I have a table that, from what I have been able to find in my research, is a somewhat special case with using lookup formulas and functions. It's much easier to show than describe so here is the screenshot of my data for an idea of what I'm working with (the actual table extends down by 60 rows and to the right by over 160 columns).  [image]

(I will refer to the values in column A as "Results", the values in row 2 as "Block numbers" and the matrix below the Block Numbers as "Reference Numbers".)

What I want to do create a formula where, if I plug in a given Block Number (for example, "BA000-") and Reference Number (for example, "040"), Excel will return a list from the Results that line up with that (in the case of my example criteria, it would list "BBB", "CCC", "EEE", "FFF" and "KKK").

I have been researching this for two days now, trying every lookup function and combination of functions that I can find (including, but not limited to, INDEX-MATCH, INDEX-MATCH-MATCH, VLOOKUP-HLOOKUP, etc). Regardless of what functions I use I keep coming up with errors. I have yet to try VBA only because I have not had time to delve into it very much for this however I am beginning to think that I'm going to have to give in to that dark side or switch to Access (with which my proficiency is much lower than Excel).

Any help would be greatly appreciated and awarded with something to the effect of 783 Karma Points (or whatever personal system of indulgence you would like me to wish to you). If you need any further information, please do not hesitate to let me know.

EDIT: I have to work on this while balancing work time (as this is a project I have been undertaking for my work) so it may take me a minute but I will try to get a table with more information to play around with. In the interim, thank you all very much for helping me out so far!

EDIT #2: [Here is a link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8XrTTcJis8WeGxEOFZQd1pSYmM/view?usp=sharing)to a sample of the file I am working with (hosted on Google Drive). I have tried to make it as clear and concise as possible but, as before, please let me know if you need any other information about it. The actual file I am working with spans all the way to column EP but I figured that that large of a file was unnecessary.

The gist of what this is is a reference tool to find what model a particular component is used in (a Bill Of Materials). After looking up the part number (in a separate file), you are given a block number and a reference number for that part which, when cross-referenced in the matrix, tells you which model that component is used in. My goal is to create an automatic search tool that will list all models a part is used in when the user enters the block and reference numbers (as the actual list of models, while all are unique, can get quite long and is tedious to filter through).

As before, any help towards achieving this goal is extremely appreciated. If any other information is needed please let me know.

Comment: If you want a VBA solution, would you be okay with a list like `BBB, CCC, EEE, FFF` in a single string/cell? Or would you need it to have one value (`BBB`, `CCC`, etc) per a cell?  (Also, instead of a screen shot, could you copy/paste data and format as a table? That helps us throw it into Excel to play around with).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a formula that will work for you.  Without knowing your exact ranges, I opted to use Named Ranges that you can replace as desired.

Named Ranges Used:

- **Results**: This is the list of your "Results" in column A (AAA, BBB, etc)
- **BlockHeaders**: This is the headers row containing the Block numbers (BA000-, BA010-, etc)
- **tblData**: This is the table of data containing your reference numbers (032, 040, etc)
- **BlockNum**: This is the cell containing the specific Block Number you are looking for (set to BA000- as per your example)
- **RefNum**: This is the cell containing the specific Reference Number you are looking for (set to 040 as per your example)

Using those named ranges, this formula should work for you assuming that all of the Results are unique (as shown in your example).  I put this formula in a separate sheet starting in cell B4 and copied down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Results,MATCH(1,INDEX((COUNTIF($B$3:$B3,Results)=0)*(INDEX(tblData,0,MATCH(BlockNum,BlockHeaders,0))=RefNum),),0)),"")
```

Comment: Wooooo - nicely done. I was scratching my head on the `Index/Match` part, and was going to work on a VBA function, but you beat me to it!

Comment: Even with all that beautiful verbiage, it didn't work for me for some reason. As I put in my edit, I will try to get a table drawn up and more information within the next little while to better help in understanding this. Still, thank you so much for that!

Comment: I realized just now why it didn't work for me before: I forgot to rename my ranges (I already had them named, but differently than you did, tigeravatar). I went back after reading MacroMarc's comment and realized I had not updated my range names and it worked absolutely perfectly. You are a saint/genius/wizard/some other person of high societal position deserving of my respect and all the cookies. Thank you very very much! :D

Answer (score 1):

tigeravatar has a good idea about Named Ranges. I would advise the same if you can.

Here is a formula entered into F10 and copied down as per my screenshot:

`=IFERROR(INDEX($A:$A, SMALL(IF(INDEX($C$4:$E$8, 0, MATCH($B$1, $C$2:$E$2, 0))=$A$1, ROW($A$4:$A$8), 1E+99), ROWS($F$10:$F10))), "")`

1) The values to search for are in A1 and B1 as you see.

2)The range `$C$4:$E$8` in the second INDEX function is the block of 'Reference Numbers'. Expand the reference or use Named Ranges(better)

3) `$C$2:$E$2` in the MATCH function are your Block codes. Expand or use Named Ranges

4) `ROW($A$4:$A$8)` needs to cover all your 'Results'. Expand or use Named Ranges

5) `ROWS($F$10:$F10)` needs to be amended to match the first cell where you want the list to appear. So if you were in AX1, you would use `ROWS($AX$1:$AX1)` - Please note dollar signs are slightly different.

[image]

Comment: Until I read your answer and realized I had been using different names for my ranges than tigeravatar, I couldn't figure out why it wouldn't work but thank you for emphasizing that; I apparently was in a daze. You solution worked perfectly for me as well and I sincerely thank you for taking the time to work on that for me, as well as your explanations. Your check is in the mail along with a spiritual bear hug. Thank you again :D

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out.